# 554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect. sending from postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I know a similar questions have been posted in different forums, but after following the recommendations I'm still stuck with this error, the problems is as follows:

I've an email server at taskgeo.com where all the notifications are sent to users, this has been working flawless for some months now, recently I started to notice the following messages in the logs:

```
Mar 28 06:37:39 djondbserver postfix/smtp[19355]: 406B85C00B5: to=<usermailXXX@bizagi.com>, relay=mail.bizagi.com[181.49.19.198]:25, delay=411817, delays=411817/0.09/0.73/0, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.bizagi.com[181.49.19.198] refused to talk to me: 554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect.)
```

(sorry I'd to change the user's email to avoid spams)

So I checked and the forums/stackoverflow/etc pointed that it may be a problem of taskgeo.com (this is the name of the email server) been black listed somewhere (public spam lists or directly at bizagi.com), so I proceed to check all the different spam servers using mxtool, with no luck, taskgeo is not reported anywhere, also I've sent an email to the admin of bizagi.com and they said that taskgeo is not in their blacklist either, and they added it to the whitelist just in case, but still the error is there, so I found out that it might be related with the PTR records not been added correctly, so I proceed to fix this and now it's pointing correctly, but I'm still getting the error, I even tried to open `telnet mail.bizagi.com 25` directly from the server and the answer is this:

```
Trying 181.49.19.198...
Connected to mail.bizagi.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

so I'm lost, Even the code error does not match to the forums I read, as 554 is usually related with other descriptions rather than `"You are not allowed to connect"`.

Can you point me in the right direction? am I right to think that taskgeo.com has been added to a blacklist inside bizagi server, or is a misconfiguration of postfix?

Additional information: emails are working fine to a wide variety of other servers, gmail, amongst them.

Thanks once more for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could assess from the error posted, it is highly likely that your mail server ip has ended up being in a private blacklist at bizagi.com. If you look at the telnet session closely, the remote server doesn't even send an "220 ... READY" response but rejects immedieately.

> Even the code error does not match to the forums I read, as 554 is
>   usually related with other descriptions rather than "You are not
>   allowed to connect"

The text in the error message can be customized at the mail server and can vary.

The codes are outlined here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml

I would recommend to contact the reciepient domain administrator again and send them the exact error response / telnet session output as an evidence. I guess either they have overlooked the case or need to investigate a little more.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought, but it's not my area of expertise so I preferred to check with expert people like yourself before sending a new question to the admin.

Comment: You are welcome. May be they have whitelisted the domain as you have requested, but the mail server ip address is still in some blacklist. But surely they can find out the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately numerous test sites do not show any sign of problem if you are blacklisted at Symantec. I had exactly that situation. You will see in the header of bounce back email message and mail server logs:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect.
```

You can check your current blacklisting status and request unlisting here:

https://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/ipr/lookup