# Workaround 554 5.7.1 Error

Tags: smtp

I've posted this question some days ago, 
[554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect. sending from postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/767255/554-5-7-1-you-are-not-allowed-to-connect-sending-from-postfix)

Based on the answer I've sent some emails to the admin of the other email server, unfortunately seems that the guy does not know what to check, and he didn't manage to sort out the problem, is there anything I can do from my side to workaround this problem? I've read that maybe using gmail smtp could be an option, but I'm wondering if this relaying will work or my server will be banned by google for misused.

Comment: `Based on the answer I've sent some emails to the admin of the other email server` - Sent them some emails regarding what? Asking them to unblock you or asking them how the weather is? Add some detail for us. If you sent them an email asking them to unblock you what was their response? What motivation would they have for unblocking you?

Comment: Asking them about the server been added to the blacklist, they said it's not added and even they said it's been added to the whitelist, still the connection is been refused as explained in the other question.